# redirect to CSS/JS files with partially known / partially unknown file names

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to use htaccess to redirect Googlebot from an incoming URL file request of this form:

`v_3099_0726dd5b5e8dd67a214c0c243436d131_all.css`

to a file of this form, where the four digits at `5028` are not known but are always four digits.

`v_5028_0726dd5b5e8dd67a214c0c243436d131_all.css`

I don't think this is possible with regex, because a catchcall regex for those four characters cannot be used in the target path.  In other words, Rewrite cannot be told, "go look in directory ____ for a file name that matches everything literally except those four characters, and match them with a regex catchall."

In RewriteCond, pattern matching with regex is only available in the right-hand side, in CondPattern, not in the left-hand side (test string) where one could have the false hope of using regex to match a file name on the server with -f flag and then using that regex grouping in a backreference in RewriteRule to accomplish the goal.  That strategy won't work.

In RewriteRule, pattern matching with regex is only available on the left-hand side, in Pattern of the incoming URL, so can't be used on the right-hand side to say, "go look in the directory ____ for a file that is the same except for these four unknown digits, and redirect to that file."  That strategy won't work, either.

Any ideas how to accomplish the goal stated at the top?  Thank you.

Comment: "to a file of this form, where the four digits at `5028` are not known" - So, how do you determine what file to redirect to? (And why only Googlebot?)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to accomplish -- figure out how I can send Googlebot to whatever the current file is, when Googlebot requests that outdated filename .  It's all the same name except those four characters.  Googlebot because I don't want it to be getting 404s when it hunts for outdated CSS/JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this in `.htaccess` alone. The file that you want to redirect/rewrite to must be "known". There's no way (in `.htaccess`) that I can see to scan a particular directory for a file that matches a particular pattern and return that instead (without the help of an external script).

(*Aside:* MultiViews allows a file with an essentially unknown extension to be served - but that's not the case here.)

You can potentially "test" the existence of various files before redirecting/rewriting to one of them, but with what looks like a "random" 4-digit number - that would be hopelessly inefficient.

However, what you could do is internally rewrite the request for such a file (that does not exist) to a server-side script (such as PHP). It would then be trivial (assuming there is just 1 file that should match this pattern) for this script to check for the "current" file and either redirect or return this file instead.

The `.htaccess` portion of this would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^v_\d{4}_[0-9a-f]{32}_all\.css$ return-current-file.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, MrWhite. That would work under your circumstances. I will have to abandon tackling it this way, though, for two reasons: 1. there are several outdated files of the same form and 2. sometimes the "new" file w/ the four new digits hasn't been created yet, at the time that googlebot comes looking for old one.  After periodic purging of CSS/JS, new versions are created when ordinary visitors hit relevant webpages.  I have decided to handle it by throwing a 410, but am struggling a bit with my request_uri not matching.  I will post the question link here, since it's a different question.

Comment: Here is the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386333/request-uri-not-matching-explicit-path-and-filename) that I mentioned.  If I can get request-uri to match, I will throw a 410 for the handful of pages like this.

Comment: MrWhite, I did the best I could with the fix below. - Jim

Comment: "1. there are several outdated files of the same form" - You would need logic that determines the "new" filename, based on the requested file. "2. sometimes the "new" file w/ the four new digits hasn't been created yet" - In that situation you have no option but to return a 404 (or 410).

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to determine why server configuration or site code was forcing '410 Gone' response directive in htaccess to be overridden with a 404 response, so had to do something like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/104242/how-to-serve-410-from-apache-rather-than-a-404) to tell googlebot to stop hunting for CSS/JS files that get purged periodically (and renamed when regenerated).

in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule v_(.*)_(.*)$ /410response.php [L]
```

in 410response.php placed in root:

`<?php header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 410 Gone');`

**UPDATE I**

The 404 response when attempting to use htaccess for the 410 directive was being forced by the server, because of server apparently having a custom 410 document, that apparently routed to 404.  Adding a directive to prevent that then properly allowed use of htaccess to return 410 for pattern matches in RewriteRule.  (I thought that I had already checked yesterday to see if this would work, since @MrWhite said in his answer above to control for server possibly having a custom 410; today when making this check, it did work and indicate that server 410-to-404 redirection was overridding my 410 directive.)

```
ErrorDocument 410 default
RewriteRule test\.txt$ - [NC,R=410]
```

MrWhite!  I located this solution in [one of your posts](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120589/return-410-gone-status-code-for-urls-containing-same-characters-in-htaccess) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Again, thanks for the feedback. However, I would have thought a 404 would be sufficient for these non-existent CSS and JS files - I'm not sure how a 410 would be beneficial here? A 410 (as opposed to a 404) can help page URLs be removed from the search results quicker, however, that is not generally a concern for CSS and JS files.

Comment: Correct, I don't know if it matters much to SEO or not.  It seems that googlebot continues to check for css and js from months if not years ago.  The 404 that it encounters does not seem to deter it from checking and re-checking and re-re-checking.  So, noticing that is what lead to all of this, and then I ran into the odd 410 behavior that complicated things.